# Python does not create window with tkinter on doubleclik

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

Im using:

- python 3
- ubuntu 16
- tkinter
- nemo as file manager

I write this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
#! python3
import tkinter as tk
# importa la libreria
mi_ventanita = tk.Tk()
# crea la ventanita
mi_ventanita.geometry("200x500") 
mi_ventanita.title("Hola")
mi_frame = tk.Frame(mi_ventanita)
mi_frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(mi_frame, text='Okay', command=quit)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
#Width x Height
mi_ventanita.mainloop()
```

And saved it in a file namede crear.py

I changed the file permissions from command line with this command:

`sudo chmod a+x *.py`

When in nemo I double click the file, appears a message:

[image]

I choose run in terminal

For one second appear a window border, but then dissapear...

If I run the code from terminal using:

```
python3 crear.py
```

The window appears!

[image]

If i debug the file using pdb:

```
python3 -m pdb crear.py
```

The window appears!

[image]

So my question is:

It is possible to open the window when I double click the file from nemo?

I have other python programs, which not use tinker, and work perfectly on double click using nemo as file manager.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you have `/usr/bin/python`?  If yes, what is the version of this Python?  And you used `python3` when you tried to run the script in ab open terminal, did you try `/usr/bin/python` instead?  I doubt that `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2, but your script requires Python 3.  Also try changing `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/env python3` in your script.

Comment: Thank you!

Using 

#!/usr/bin/env python3

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Linux of Ubuntu, but I see 2 problems:

```
button = tk.Button(mi_frame, text='Okay', command=quit)
```

1. The quit has to be in quotation marks

```
button = tk.Button(mi_frame, text='Okay', command="quit")
```

2. Commands are not built in, meaning when you pass a parameter in the command option, you are actually executing a function when the button is clicked

```
def quit():
     return
button = tk.Button(mi_frame, text='Okay', command="quit")
```

Comment: `command=quit` is correct, but `command="quit"` is not.

Answer (score 0):

A work around:

I created an sh file with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash  
python3 crear.py
```

Saved and make it executable.

When i double click the sh file, python creates the window...

Answer (score 0):

As acw1688 wrote, the solution was using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

So the working code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
import tkinter as tk
# importa la libreria
mi_ventanita = tk.Tk()
# crea la ventanita
mi_ventanita.geometry("200x500") 
mi_ventanita.title("Hola")
mi_frame = tk.Frame(mi_ventanita)
mi_frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(mi_frame, text='Okay', command=quit)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
#Width x Height
mi_ventanita.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much!